# Tomcat - want to clear cache of app being undeployed

Tags: war, tomcat6

I've got Tomcat6 running on my Ubuntu server 14.04 minimal platform and had deployed a .war file.

However, things did not go right during the initial setup of the app and I'm trying to undeploy the app from tomcat manager.
Unfortunately when I re-deploy the app and start it, the previous install comes up.

How can I get a fresh install of the app? (I've also tried "reload" but no luck)

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 6):

In Tomcat you have a  folder  called "work".

```
Go to <TOMCAT_HOME>/work/Catalina/<HOSTNAME>
```

In this location you will find your application. Delete the application from this location and try to redeploy your application and give a try !!!

Comment: when I'm undeploying the app, it's folder is being removed from the Catalina folder. The app name is OpenMRS and when deployed, it's directory is **var/lib/tomcat6/work/Catalina/localhost/openmrs** however, when I undeploy openmrs, there is now no openmrs folder in **var/lib/tomcat6/work/Catalina/localhost/** yet when I deploy openmrs again, it loads form the previous install.

Comment: stop > undeploy > delete the app in the /work/... folder > then add the new version to webapps and startup tomcat again.
it's damn annoying and it doesn't happen in windows7

Comment: You may need to delete the tmp directory as well